# gcloud kubectl - Unable to find specific git commit from GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, gcloud, kubectl, google-anthos

`gcloud` was installed using this command in windows Powershell:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe", "$env:Temp\GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe")

& $env:Temp\GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe
```

---

```
$ gcloud -v
Google Cloud SDK 398.0.0
anthos-auth 1.4.3
```

---

```
$ gcloud components install kubectl

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22+", GitVersion:"v1.22.12-dispatcher-dirty", GitCommit:"fde00375407ad0afadd681a3505054ec83f935ec", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2022-07-19T19:06:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5-gke.1200", GitCommit:"90a16981ade07f163a0233adb631b42ac1fc53ff", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-04T09:25:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7b7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

---

Above client version tool has git commit `fde00375407ad0afadd681a3505054ec83f935ec`

Here is the open source repo for `kubectl` : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl

Not sure, if gcloud uses the same repo

---

How to find this  specific Git commit from gcloud's `kubectl` source repo? `fde00375407ad0afadd681a3505054ec83f935ec`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a commit with that hash in that repository, so you can't.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I installed `kubectl` with `gcloud components install kubectl`

Comment: Okay, I don't know what to do with this information though.

Comment: The release was built from that commit. That does not mean the commit is available today.

Comment: @JohnHanley commit history should have that commit, Isn't it? Do you mean the commit would have been deleted?

Comment: @JohnHanley does gcloud use kubectl component built from this repo? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl

Comment: I do not know that level of detail. What is your objective?

Comment: @JohnHanley Am unable to load oidc based config as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73396202/3317808), so... I would like mimic, kubectl functionality, for the same

Comment: What does OIDC have to do with a GitHub commit?

Comment: @JohnHanley kubectl commit(`fde00375407ad0afadd681a3505054ec83f935ec`) has the functionality to load OIDC based authentication. Would like to browse that code and mimic the functionality

Comment: OIDC is OpenID Connect. There are zillions of examples on the Internet. I wrote a few. Google has good examples on its website. Start with OAuth and understand that. OIDC is a layer on top of OAuth. Regarding the kubectl commit, review the latest development version.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes there are many examples(like https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc) for OIDC authentication. Goal is to to get the state of pods(& other resources) from the cluster after successful authentication. . I could not find any example on managing the cluster, after OIDC authentication

Comment: OAuth/OIDC are methods of authorization. Other than authorization, that has little to do with fetching the state of pods, etc. I think what you want is the GKE API: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest You will need to understand the GKE API to read the tool source code.

Comment: @JohnHanley Before using GKE API, Does the api client need to authenticate using OIDC? In our environment, all kubernetes clusters accept OIDC authentication.

Comment: There are two types of OAuth authentication in Google Cloud. OAuth Access Tokens and OIDC Identity Tokens. Which one to use depends on the API. In general, Google Cloud APIs use OAuth Access Tokens. Read the GKE API docs and it will tell you what authorization you must provide. Typically in the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` However, this subject is complex/large enough that I could write a book.

Comment: @JohnHanley we are planning to write client library that talks to kubernetes API server(of kubernetes control plane) but not GKEngine.

Comment: There are already many. Do not reinvent the wheel unless you have something new and important to add unless this is a learning journey. One method to master a technology is to learn its inner core and interfaces. The code for Kubernetes is public so you will have excellent resources to dig into.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, we are consuming client library(https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to write a tool. Sorry, my bad, we are not writing library, but consuming client library, but we are getting into this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73396202/3317808).

Comment: I tried installing `kubectl` using the gcloud components command and I got some error but it suggested to run the command `sudo apt-get install kubectl` to achieve the same result.  https://imgur.com/vXri6CH  Also, the kubectl component are also listed in the [apt and yum package](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#external_package_managers) in the gcp docs

Comment: @JohnHanley Can you share golang example with google api that performs OIDC authentication? I could see an example in java...https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#java

Comment: Which service is the code calling that requires OIDC Identity Tokens? Most of the services have examples either online or in the SDK or both.

Comment: @JohnHanley code is calling service https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go